# ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-align/es/Align.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

Project was working fine until today, it keeps getting this error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/rc-align/es/Align.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rc-util/es/Dom/isVisible' in '/Users/faizan/Simplus/Unilever/visum-web/node_modules/rc-align/es'
```

I have tried reinstalling the node_modules but still it does not help and i can't seem to find any solution for it.

Comment: I have the same issue after an `npm update`. Do you have a splution to this?